# Flyway baseline script is not executing on new machine

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, maven, flyway

I've been trying to squash our flyway scripts. The way i am thinking is: first get a baseline script that will execute on new (test) machines. After that update our PROD schema_version table so that flyway thinks it has executed the baseline. After that is done delete the previous scripts.

I've found the following articles:
https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/tutorial-baseline-migrations-184127615.html
https://medium.com/att-israel/flyway-squashing-migrations-2993d75dae96

I know for the baseline to work you will need the (paid) flyway teams edition. Which we are using. We use the flyway maven plugin so every script will be executed on startup. We use the flyway-core from the enterprise edition version 8.5.9

name of the script: `B3_0_001__baseline_init.sql`
I've changed the name to `V3_0_001__baseline_init.sql` to check if something was wrong with the naming or sql itself but this script was executed perfectly. We use flyway in combination with postgres but that shouldn't be a problem because the normal script worked just fine.

After i drop my schema and re-run our application no baseline script is executed but the other scripts are.

Does anyone know why the script isn't executing on new machines?

P.s. it is a spring-boot application